# How to calculate/ visualize a defect escape metric in Github?

Tags: metrics

Inside of our team we decided to start calculating/ visualising defect escape metrics (how many bugs are found before prod vs how many bugs are found in prod).

We use Github to track our issues.

Are there any tools which allow to build the graphs/see the trends based on the Github Issues labels?

For now I found a possibility to do it in Jira (by adding a designated field for when the bug was found) or in Targetprocess. The problem with these two is that they need to be a main tool for tracing issues to be able to perform this task. We don't want to move from Github Issues somewhere else so it's not an option.

Comment: Are you looking for a native way to do this in GitHub? If so, it's not possible. You'll need to go to a third-party tool. There are tools that can do visualization and reporting of GitHub issues based on date created, labels, and other fields that GitHub natively provides. These tools will probably cost money, especially if you're using them on private repos.

Comment: https://9-volt.github.io/bug-life/?repo=deanmalmgren/textract

Comment: This site looks promising

Answer (score 1):

[GitHub's API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/issues) allows you to fetch the list of issues filtering by label.

[image]

It will return a list of objects representing each issue-bug, which you can use to chart out as you wish.

[image]